# Bootstrap 5 Icon Wont Appear

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am making a website and I am trying to use a bootstrap 5 icon but it won't appear. This is what it looks like [![Example1][1]][1] This is what it is supposed to look like [![Example2][2]][2]

### Code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Your awesome title: Name</title>

<meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="/_bridgetown/static/js/main.96ffffaea92690057bfb.js" defer></script>
```

```html
<!-- USER DETAILS START -->
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center pt-4"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x"></i>
      <h2 class="display-6">100</h2>
      <p class="text-muted">Active Clients</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-windows fa-3x"></i>
      <h2 class="display-6>100</h2>
      <p class="text-muted">Active Clients</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- USER DETAILS CLOSE -->
```

Comment: Just an advice. In 2023 you don’t need bootstrap anymore. We have css grids, much better much faster and responsive, without making users download more code. The same applies font awesome, instead of makin users download a bunch of unused icons, css and font files, just go to svg repo, download the icon you really need in SVG format and set a width or height to it for less than 1 kb 

Comment: But if you want to use it, the code you show us (fa user) is not from bootstrap but from font-awesome so you need to add the font awesome library to make it work

Comment: @Marcus Petersen thank you, how would I add the font awesome library?

Comment: I added an answer with the correct code for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to use Font Awesome icons in your Bootstrap 5 project. However, you have not included the Font Awesome library in your project.

Add it using this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+Knujsl5/6en8XCp+HHAAK5GSLf2xlYtvJ8U2Q4U+9cuEnJoa3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Update the classes in your html code like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <i class="fas fa-user fa-3x"></i>
  <h2 class="display-6">100</h2>
  <p class="text-muted">Active Clients</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the font awesome library

Just add the following line after the title

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
```

And it will work

Or copy and paste/replace the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Your awesome title: Technovine Solutions</title>

<meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." />


 <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="/_bridgetown/static/js/main.96ffffaea92690057bfb.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: I wanted to ask if you knew a free alternative to font awesome because most of the icons are locked behind a pay wall.

Comment: Font awesome has thousands of free icons. But you can also find the premium ones on internet. I cannot tell you how but it is possible to do by looking the source code of some websites